Delayed audio start/stop after Ubuntu 24.04 upgrade, slow pipewire
Anytime I either

make any bell noise in my gnome terminal
mute/unmute/change volume in gnome
start, pause or continue a video on firefox

I get

the quiet but audible pop that you hear when audio is unmuted
a ~5 second (!) delay
the sound playing

When stopping the sound, the same happens in reverse order, with a shorter delay.
I suspect that the audio system (pipewire) is opening and closing an interface, and has perhaps some driver issues? How can I debug this annoying delay?
journalctl shows during such an event:
Mai 28 21:46:42 generic kernel: cs35l41-hda spi0-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.0: Requesting Firmware Load after HDA_GEN_PCM_ACT_CLOSE
Mai 28 21:46:42 generic kernel: cs35l41-hda spi0-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.1: Requesting Firmware Load after HDA_GEN_PCM_ACT_CLOSE
Mai 28 21:46:42 generic kernel: cs35l41-hda spi0-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.0: Bypassing Firmware.
Mai 28 21:46:42 generic kernel: cs35l41-hda spi0-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.1: Bypassing Firmware.
Mai 28 21:46:56 generic kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1716925616.179:3178): pid=2334 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.1" mask="receive" pid=84389 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=2327 peer_label="unconfined"
                                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Mai 28 21:46:56 generic kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1716925616.180:3179): pid=2334 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.1" mask="receive" pid=84389 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=2327 peer_label="unconfined"
                                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Mai 28 21:46:56 generic kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1716925616.190:3180): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/igfx_user_feature_next.txt" pid=84389 comm="FSBroker92957" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mai 28 21:46:56 generic kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1716925616.191:3181): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/igfx_user_feature.txt" pid=84389 comm="FSBroker92957" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mai 28 21:47:08 generic kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1716925628.659:3182): pid=2334 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.1" mask="receive" pid=84389 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=2327 peer_label="unconfined"
                                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Mai 28 21:47:08 generic kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1716925628.660:3183): pid=2334 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.1" mask="receive" pid=84389 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=2327 peer_label="unconfined"
                                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Mai 28 21:47:13 generic kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1716925633.677:3184): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/igfx_user_feature.txt" pid=84389 comm="FSBroker92957" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mai 28 21:47:13 generic kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1716925633.678:3185): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/igfx_user_feature_next.txt" pid=84389 comm="FSBroker92957" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mai 28 21:47:14 generic kernel: cs35l41-hda spi0-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.0: Requesting Firmware Load after HDA_GEN_PCM_ACT_CLOSE
Mai 28 21:47:14 generic kernel: cs35l41-hda spi0-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.1: Requesting Firmware Load after HDA_GEN_PCM_ACT_CLOSE
Mai 28 21:47:14 generic kernel: cs35l41-hda spi0-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.0: Bypassing Firmware.
Mai 28 21:47:14 generic kernel: cs35l41-hda spi0-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.1: Bypassing Firmware.

I see pipewire-pulse running.
This is on a Dell XPS 15, and the problem occurs both with and without using headphones.

I have exactly the same issue, on my Dell XPS 15, as a workaround, i use my external screen'speaker: it works fine without delay.

Ah! So I'm not the only one, it seems to be a Dell XPS 15 issue.

possibly related https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/issues/2894 but I could not find the wireplumber configuration folder in ubuntu

I followed (more or less) the link provided by j13r: I uncommented this line
  --["session.suspend-timeout-seconds"] = 0,  -- 0 disables suspend

in /usr/share/wireplumber/main.lua.d/50-alsa-config.lua on my kubuntu
I restarted wireplumber
systemctl --user restart wireplumber

This is just a workaround but it seems ok now.

Unfortunately this workaround doesn't seem to work for me.

Works for me. Ubuntu 24.04
